# Refreshing Webdriver page until element is displayed

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a script in Ruby with the Selenium-Webdriver and have been trying to come up with a loop that will refresh the current page until a certain element id is present.  My current code looks like the following:

```
until driver.find_element(:id => "test").displayed?
 puts "#{driver.title} not live - reloading..."
 driver.navigate.refresh
end
```

However when executed, this brings the whole script to a halt without refreshing the page (but doesn't throw any errors).  I tried substituting the `driver.navigate.refresh` with `driver.get "http://website"`, but I get the same results.

In order to diagnose the problem, I've attempted to see what my first line is returning.  When the element with id "test" **is** found, a `puts driver.find_element(:id => "test").displayed?` will return "true" to the console.  If element "test" is **not** found, the console hangs without returning anything.  It's my guess that I need to implement some kind of timer to force the script to give up searching for the element, but I was hoping it would figure this out dynamically (depending on how long it took to interpret the page).

Any help with getting this loop working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why should you need to refresh until a certain ID is found? Is it displaying randomly? Does it only appear after a certain number of page refreshes? It doesn't sound like a good test either way; If it's a random thing, you could end up waiting a long time. If it's after a certain number of refreshes, can't you set up the pre-conditions that would make it occur so you can force its display?

Comment: The script is meant to query a page for a product, waiting for it to go live.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace

```
driver.navigate.refresh
```

with

```
driver.navigate.to "http://page to refresh"
```

A little brute force, but it shouldn't stop the script this way.

I'd also add a wait command so you don't get into somekind of infinite loop.

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30)
wait.until{driver.find_element(:name, 'test')}
```

If after 3 seconds there is still no sighting of the desired element, the page should refresh.

I hope this helps

Comment: I'd rather not introduce a delay requirement.  Ideally, the driver will get the page, scan it for the element, and if it doesn't appear, immediately reload - continuously doing so until the element is present.